# Rails Tutorial user.save giving Argument Error (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

First off, bit of a noob with posting on here, so just let me know if my formatting is off or anything like that, I'll be happy to fix it :)

I've been following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and its been great. I'm sure my issue is due to me not doing something properly, but I can't find anything on the web that would fix my problem.

I'm in Chapter 6 creating a user database. Everything works fine up until I try to do `user.save`

Just for reference, here's the steps leading up to the problem:

```
rails generate model User name:string email:string
```

and then:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

open up a sandboxed console:

```
 rails console --sandbox
```

Make a new user

```
user = User.new(name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhartl@example.com")
```

Save it:

```
user.save
```

Everything gives me the expected outputs up until user.save which gives this

> irb(main):002:0> user.save
>      (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
>      (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
>   ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adap
>   ters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `initialize'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adap
>   ters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in`new'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adap
>   ters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `substitute_at'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:97:
>   in`block in substitute_values'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:
>   in `each'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:
>   in`each_with_index'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:
>   in `substitute_values'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:56:
>   in`insert'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:
>   521:in `_create_record'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/counter_cache.r
>   b:139:in`_create_record'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/attribute_metho
>   ds/dirty.rb:122:in `_create_record'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:30
>   6:in`block in _create_record'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:
>   88:in `call'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:
>   88:in`_run_callbacks'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:
>   734:in `_run_create_callbacks'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:30
>   6:in`_create_record'
>   ... 22 levels...
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `s
>   tart'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:
>   68:in`console'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:
>   39:in `run_command!'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
>   rb:252:in `require'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
>   rb:252:in`block in require'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
>   rb:237:in `load_dependency'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
>   rb:252:in`require'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/RoR/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
>   rb:246:in`load'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
>   rb:246:in `block in load'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
>   rb:237:in`load_dependency'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
>   rb:246:in `load'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>           from /Users/Jonathon/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>           from -e:1:in`'irb(main):003:0>

I've put my user.rb file here:

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end`

and my create_users.rb file here as well

`class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end`

Thanks and let me know if there's anymore information I need to provide!

Comment: Does it give you an error if you run it in 'bundle exec rails console', without '--sandbox' ?

Comment: No it doesn't. Just loads the console like normal

Comment: Your steps looks good; I just tried them and the call to #save worked fine. There's something messed up in your environment, but it's hard to tell what. Can you do anything to get a clean environment?

Comment: Hmm. I could try grabbing his commit of github. Lemme try that

Comment: Try the same steps but without passing the sandbox option to the rails console. Also try `user = User.create(options)` instead of `user = User.new(options)` and `user.save` just to see what happens. It's quite weird, to be honest. You might need to restart the tutorial and note any problems / problematic messages that you encounter.

Comment: I've already done it without sandbox :( the weird thing is I don't recall running into any errors or messages at all

Comment: reset your database and try again. `rake db:reset` (CAUTION: It will wipe off any saved data)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys!

Slothbear was right, ended up being a problem with my database. Cloned the tutorial git and the problems were solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. At first I have `ArgumentError` when I tried `user.save` like you did. And then when I tried `rake db:drop` and then `rake db:migrate`, also I met the same error.

It was after `bundle update` for my case and I found this `arel` gem version makes the problem. It shows `arel (6.0.0)` on Gemfile.lock but when I tried `arel (6.0.0.beta2)` as like before, it worked.

I don't know why. I found [this discussion](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext-serializers/issues/14) though. Now we don't have problem with non-beta Rails 4.2.0, and no problem with Hartl tutorial if we don't `bundle update` on the sample app (as the author said)